# AzureAD Module on Azure Functions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Having issues with AzureAD module running on Azure Functions

- Have AzureAD updated in requirements.psd1
- Restarted the Function App
- Importing the module with -UseWindowsPowerShell

Code:

```
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell;

$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $secpasswd);

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred;
```

And i get this error:

```
2022-10-08T03:23:21Z   [Warning]   WARNING: Module AzureAD is loaded in Windows PowerShell using WinPSCompatSession remoting session; please note that all input and output of commands from this module will be deserialized objects. If you want to load this module into PowerShell please use 'Import-Module -SkipEditionCheck' syntax.
2022-10-08T03:23:23Z   [Error]   ERROR: One or more errors occurred.: 

OriginInfo            : localhost
Exception             : 
    Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
    SerializedRemoteException      : Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadAuthenticationFailedException: One or more errors occurred.:  ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest). ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: : Unknown error
                                     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                                     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                                     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Http.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__22`1.MoveNext()
                                     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Http.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
                                     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.OAuth2.UserRealmDiscoveryResponse.<CreateByDiscoveryAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
                                     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenNonInteractiveHandler.<PreTokenRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
                                     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__57.MoveNext()
                                     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
                                     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
                                     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                                     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
                                     at Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.UserTokenProvider.DoAcquireToken(AdalConfiguration config, PromptBehavior promptBehavior, String userId, SecureString password) in X:\bt\1218881\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V2\CommonLibrary\TokenProvider\UserTokenProvider.cs:line 228
                                     at Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.UserTokenProvider.SafeAquireToken(AdalConfiguration config, ShowDialog showDialog, String userId, SecureString password, Exception& ex) in X:\bt\1218881\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V2\CommonLibrary\TokenProvider\UserTokenProvider.cs:line 152
                                     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 0):

After reproduced from my end, I found an approach to resolve the error:

To `connect-AzureAD`, Ps object is using Microsoft authentication library. You need to  [Update your applications to use Microsoft Authentication Library](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/update-your-applications-to-use-microsoft-authentication-library/ba-p/1257363)  in `Azure Poweshell` .
*Or*
Try giving this PowerShell command to update the module libraries.
`Get-InstalledModule -Name Az | Update-Module`

> You can give `-Force` after `Update-Module` to avoid the prompt like "untrusted repository" while installing/updating each module.

I have created a `Function App` with the configuration as below:

[image]

Make sure you added `'AzureAD' = '2.*'` in `requirements.psd1` under App files.

After updating the modules and configuration, below is the **script** to `connect-AzureAD` by providing the user credentials:

```
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
Import-Module -Name 'AzureAD' -UseWindowsPowershell
$secureStringPwd = "Password"
$secureStringPwd = $secureStringPwd|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
($credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('xxxxxx@mydomain.com', $secureStringPwd))
Connect-AzureAD -credential $credential
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
Body = $body
})
```

**Output:**

[image]

*You can also try this approach to* [Connect-AzureAD](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2302789-connect-azuread-for-script-automation) *alternatively*.

*If required, you can* check [Dotnet library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/) *to avoid any other Microsoft authentication issues.*